# Merge two images.png to output.png using gd

Tags: php, gd

I have been trying to merge two images using gd lib.
A card (background), and a "new" frame for that card (foreground, with transparent middle).

This is my code:

```
<?php
    
    $card = imagecreatefrompng('img/folder1/card.png');
    $frame = imagecreatefrompng('img/folder2/frame.png');
    
    list($width,$height) = getimagesize($frame);
    
    imagealphablending($card, true);
    imagesavealpha($card, true);
    
    imagecopy($card, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($card);
```

I do get an output, but it is only the card without the frame.

Kind regards,
ZF

<s>Edit (12h later):
I figured out why my output is the card (background) only, regardless of my changes.</s>

I deleted the last value **100** after *$height*:

```
imagecopy($card, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

Now my output is only *frame.png*.
It doesn't matter if I use *ImageAlphaBlending*.

But I know that *card.png* is definitely under *frame.png*, because I moved the *frame.png* to the side on an axis, and the card.png gets visible.
So it fails on merging the images together, respecting the transparency of *frame.png*

If I save the output to a file, it is a transparent .png tho.

Is *imagecopy* even suitable to merge *frame.png* with a transparent middle onto a background (*card.png*)?

Edit:
Sorry for the mess!
I was working with two versions at the same time.
I have cleared up my current workspace now and wrote a new version from scratch.

I did delete the **100** after *$height* in the version I posted here:

```
imagecopy($card, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);
```

Clarification to previous edit: Nothing changed at all.
The output was still only *card.png*.

BUT the code of my new version is (**Final & Working**):

```
<?php

$card = imagecreatefrompng('img/folder1/card.png');
$frame = imagecreatefrompng('img/folder2/frame.png');

$width = "402"; $height = "599";

imagealphablending($card, true);
imagesavealpha($card, true);

imagecopy($card, $frame, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height);

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($card);

imagedestroy($card);
imagedestroy($frame);
```

As you may notice I hardcoded the image *width* and *height*.
Instead of using *getimagesize*

```
list($width,$height) = getimagesize($frame);
```

I did check the output from *$width*, *$height* before and they are correct, but that seemed to be my problem.
If someone has an answer to that, feel free to explain!

Comment: Cool! Good job! I prefer to work with imagick instead gd. imagick is also faster.

Comment: because of the getimagesize problem. Actually, it should work like this. Maybe it's the PNGs themselves. For example, wrong format type.
You can display the type: list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("image_name.png"); 

PNG should be type 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I abandoned the project for quite a while.
As [Maik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14807111/maik-lowrey) suggested, it could have been a .png format problem.

What should I say... advice, and therefore knowledge, comes with time:

In fact the error was not produced by `getimagesize` and hardcoding the image size is not necessary.

It was a plain image format problem.

The mentioned "New Version" I wrote from scratch simply used different .png images with the right format.

I just didn't know this at that time, because I apparently got the *same* image from the creator, but it have been different renderings and thereby different format types.

Upvotes to Maik, and check your .png format type (type 3).

Edit: Oh and maybe take a look at imagick  ;)